# Cut numeric vars in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I'm struggling with looping through a list of numeric col names, using cut() and group_by() to summarize a 'e' by bins of the other vars. The below code gives error "'x' must be numeric", in reference to the mutate step.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(a = round(rnorm(50, 1,1.5),2),
                 b = round(rnorm(50, 1,1.5),2),
                 c = round(rnorm(50, 1,1.5),2),
                 d = round(rnorm(50, 1,1.5),2),
                 e = round(rnorm(50, 1,1.5),2))
nums <- colnames(df[,1:4])
for (i in nums) {
  summary <- df %>%
    mutate(z = cut(i, seq(min(i),max(i),length.out = 10), include.lowest = TRUE)) #%>%
    group_by(z) %>%
    summarise(e = sum(e))
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `!!ensym(i)` instread of `i`

Comment: That does the trick - is there an analogous function for this in base R?

Comment: @JackAndrew `tidyvers` has  different non-standard evaluation (NSE) ecosystem than base R see [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

Comment: @AaronMontgomery `ensym`  transfer a string into symbol then `!!` evaluate it in the right environment/context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way

```
x <- letters[1:4] %>% 
  purrr::set_names()

sum_grp_fun <- function(x){
  df %>% 
    mutate(grp = cut(.data[[x]],
                     seq(min(.data[[x]]),max(.data[[x]]),length.out = 10),
                     include.lowest = TRUE)) %>% 
    group_by(grp) %>% 
    summarise(e = sum(e))
}

map(.x = x, ~ sum_grp_fun(.x))
```